# Get value from returned json

Tags: android, json, parsing

So I'm new to json parsing in general.  With the help of the community I was able to get the json returned.  However, for the life of me can not figure out how to access/get certain values.  I am trying to get/access the "halfjpeg" value in the "content" section.

```
[
  {
    "publicId": "1337",
    "name": "mypainting",
    "orientation": "vertical",
    "provider": "user",
    "providerFullName": "unknown",
    "location": {
      "coordinates": [
        -71,
        42
      ],
      "userCityCode": "BOS",
      "userCityName": "Boston",
      "userStateCode": "MA",
      "userStateName": "Massachusetts",
      "userCountryCode": "US",
      "userCountryName": "United States",
      "userZipCode": "02108",
      "latitude": 42
      "longitude": -71
    },
    "status": {
      "isLive": false,
      "isCertified": false,
      "hasVirusWarning": true
    },
    "content": {
      "halfJpeg": "userhalfpaintlocation.com",
      "fullJpeg": "userfullpaintlocation.com",
      "hugeJpeg": "userhugepaintlocation.com"
    },
    "createdAt": xxxxxxxx,
    "updatedAt": xxxxxxxx,
    "policy": {
      "isAdmin": false,
      "isUser": true
    }
  }
]
```

My code to get JSON is below:

```
URL url = null;
        try {
            url = new URL("getthepaintingurl.com");
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        try {
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        } catch (ProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            System.out.println("Response Code: " + conn.getResponseCode());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        InputStream in = null;
        try {
            in = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        try {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                out.append(line + "\n");

            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println(out.toString());

        try {
            JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(out.toString());
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Did you tried to google a little before ask a question?

Comment: You're starting with a `JSONArray` by the looks of it: here's everything you need to know: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/package-summary.html

Comment: Yup, i've tried parsing myself, but can never seem to access the right node/child correctly.

Comment: You should be able to in the way I answered below

Comment: Thank you! Works like a charm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.w3schools.com/json/json_syntax.asp

Just so you are aware of some syntax, read the above (it should help clarify!).

You the response you are expecting is in the form of a JSONArray. So it would look something like this:

```
//create json array from the buffer string, and get the inner json object
JSONObject response = new JSONArray(out.toString()).getJSONObject(0);

//get the json object at key "content"
JSONObject content = response.getJSONObject("content");

//access the value of "halfJpg"
String halfJpgSrc = content.getString("halfJpeg");
```

Comments should explain themselves, but you essentially create a JSONArray from the output from your request, and access the inner json object which contains all the information (index 0). Then you just navigate to the data you sent. In this case, the inner data is stored in key/value pairs so it should be pretty self explanatory how to access anything else within your JSON response.

Here is more documentation on those two objects (JSONArray / JSONObject)

[JSONObject](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html) [JSONArray](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONArray.html)

Comment: Lucas - thank you very much!  The explanation was extremely helpful and thorough.  My problem before was I was assigning the index[0] to the 'content' and not the response object. Thanks again!

Comment: Lucas - just wanted to thank you again.  It's been a week or so, but wanted to let you know your explanation and answer have helped me grasp JSON Objects much better.

Comment: No problem, I am glad I was able to help you learn about a fairly important data type that you will consistently see in Android development. JSON is every where, most modern REST APIs are using JSON responses / requests, so it is important to understand. Hope your project is turning out well!